# 2008 R2 Cluster not failing over with iSCSI disconnect

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cluster

So I have successfully set up a 2 node 2008 R2 cluster with SQL Server 2008.

There are basically 3 networks.

- Public (client LAN)
- Private (Heartbeat between the two machines)
- iSCSI SAN (hosts witness disk and SQL storage)

I have had the cluster successfully failover by disconnecting the public network, by manually transferring the service, and by rebooting one of the machines.

What I cant get get to failover is when I pull the iSCSI network connection from the hosting machine. The service falls flat on its face and doesn't recover until I plug back in and manually bring the service online.

My quorum mode is `Node and Disk Majority`.

My understanding is that if Machine 1 loses its connection to either the public network or the iSCSI resource, that the whole cluster should failover to Machine 2 which still has an established connection to both networks.

Comment: did this pass the cluster validation test?

Comment: yes. and all services failover and failback properly if I do it manually through the management console

Comment: I had a similar issue with a cheap iscsi device it didn't really support persistent reservations wonder if thats an issue here.

Comment: While we didnt go for a very expensive HP or Dell iSCSI solution, this isnt exactly a cheap unit either. Its made by QNAP. According to their site it supports `SPC-3 Persistent Reservation` [QNAP Software Spec](http://www.qnap.com/USEng/pro_detail_software.asp?p_id=184)

Comment: qnap was the device that I used and it was not compliant with spc-3 at the time. But from what I've read that currently should be a non issue. When you did cluster validation test did you skip storage?

Comment: no, I ran all tests, and all the storage passed

Comment: and what do you see in the eventlogs concerning clustering?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2919/discussion-between-brian-and-tony-roth)